# Vega-lite aggregate join

Tags: vega-lite

I have a data set with the following basic structure:

```
response_id | question_id | question_type | question_key | question_value

1           |           1 | demographic   | age          | 23
1           |           2 | value         | enjoyment    | 0.75
1           |           3 | value         | speed        | 0.95
1           |           4 | demographic   | gender       | o
2           |           5 | demographic   | age          | 55
2           |           6 | value         | enjoyment    | 0.2
2           |           7 | value         | speed        | 0.15
2           |           8 | demographic   | gender       | m
...
```

I need to produce a variety of charts which compare these responses in different ways, aggregated over common `response_id`.

How can I join on `response_id` and then filter and aggregate based on lookups of `question_type AND question_value` pairs?

#### Chart 1

An example of a simple chart would be a horizontal bar chart showing the average of `question_value` on the Y axis, filtering on `question_type = 'value'` with a bar for each unique `question_key`.

So There would be a bar for `question_key = 'enjoyment'` and a bar for `question_key = 'speed'`. There can be different numbers of possible `question_keys` which will dynamically change i.e. `speed` and `enjoyment` are not fixed and known before hand and so the chart might have different numbers of bars.

#### Chart 2

Now I want to create a new chart which pivots over chart 1. Each bar in the above chart is split into two different bars over `question_type = 'demographic' AND question_key = 'gender'`. So for each bar above there would now be two bars for `gender='m'` and `gender='o'`. So I'd have bars like: `enjoyment,m`, `enjoyment,o`, `speed,m`, `speed,o`. All of the `gender='m'` would be one color and all of the `gender='o'` would be another color.

#### Chart 3

Next I might want to pivot chart 1 above again but over ages so `question_type='demographic' AND question_key='age'` and then bin the age results into 10 year bins. So I have `enjoyment,age=1-10`, `enjoyment,age=11-20`, `enjoyment,age=21-30` ... `speed,age=1-10`, `speed,age=11-20`..., etc.

These pivots are fixed, so I'll always do a chart with `question_type='demographic' AND question_key='gender'` with those exact values for the filter, however the `question_type='value'` keys are not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a bar chart, a grouped bar chart, and a faceted grouped bar chart. have a look at the `facet` operator in Vega-Lite and how you can use it to create the charts you want.